# Denied entry to the UK after having student visa refused a week earlier, what are my options now?

Tags: uk, visas-on-arrival, removal, evidence

On the 1st of September my Tier 4 student visa application was rejected but I made the mistake of thinking I was still entitled to enter the UK with my US passport. I had already purchased a Eurostar ticket to London so I thought I could put it to use to visit some friends (one of them being my boyfriend) for two weeks before their school years started. On the 9th, I was detained in Paris and refused entry to the UK on the grounds that I recently showed "intention to live and study in the UK" and they weren't convinced I would be leaving when I said I would. Additionally, I didn't carry any documents aside from my passport, my Swiss residence permit and a copy of my passport. I am also unemployed but I am still completely financially dependent on my parents. Staying with my boyfriend was the cherry on top.

In hindsight, I acknowledge that I raised every red flag. It was like a twisted skit. However, the last time I traveled outside of Schengen was when I was 15 (I'm 19) and any recent travel I've done was by rail so I didn't anticipate the seriousness of crossing the border. It was my first time traveling alone but I suppose that level of cluelessness warrants learning the hard way.

At this point, I'm wondering what my next move should be. How long do I have to wait? I definitely want to visit the UK some time soon because I now have an unexpected gap year lying in front of me. My intentions were strictly for leisure and I wouldn't attempt anything along the lines of volunteer work while I'm there. I just want to visit my friends/boyfriend for 1-2 weeks at most. Should I apply for a visitor visa this time or can I try traveling there again but making sure I have as many documents as possible? I'm worried about getting denied entry again and having an even more "tarnished" record, so that's the main thing I want to avoid. I tried contacting the UKVI by email but they haven't responded.

Keep in mind, I'm planning on reapplying for a student visa next summer so I have no idea what I can and can't do - I really don't want to compromise anything.

Comment: Closed out. If you have more questions, please join the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) where you can engage whoever's in the room. It's great!